# Using gradle implementation of my flavoured Library causes java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, jitpack

Hey everyone I have my own developed SDK in where I few external libraries, everything works fine if the flavour is default type but issue occurs when i change the flavour then I get     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineData;

and on every library that is implemented in my SDK

i searched all over and couldn't find any solution to it

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineData;
```